# Angular databinding

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have been learning angular, and I have come across an issue, that gives me an error in my code editor, but not in the browser.

I have set a property to be interpreted as a string. However, in the constructor, I have updated the property to a number.

I get an error in vsCode, but it runs just fine in the browser. I've posted the code below.

```
export class SandboxComponent{
    name:string = 'John Doe';

    constructor(){
        this.name = 34;
    }
}
```

[This is a picture of the code running in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKC1l.png)
[This is a picture of the code in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gfyS.jpg)

The error that I get in VSCode says that the type 34 is not assignable to a string, which is true. The browser should do the same thing, but it converts it to a string and then displays it.

Why do I not get an error in the browser, but I get one in VSCode?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to add as much evidence as I can. The question is why do I not get an error in the browser, but I get one in VSCode?

Comment: **what is the error** you are getting?  providing screenshots of portions of your screen doesn't give enough information....

Comment: the typescript is compiled in javascript, and javascript is a dynamic typing language
then you will have a typeScript compilation error but you will not have a problem in browser

Comment: The error that I get in VSCode says that the type 34 is not assignable to a string, which is true. The browser should do the same thing, but it converts it to a string and then displays it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though your TypeScript code contains an error (redefining variable with value of different type), the transpiler still performs the transpilation, returning JavaScript code.

JavaScript code is then run by browser. JavaScript is a dynamically typed language, which allows redefining variable with value of different type, and that is why you are not getting an error in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You defined name variable as string but you are assigning a number to it later. This is not legal in TypeScript. To fix this you can do:

```
this.name= new Number(34).toString();
```

Comment: OP hasn't even asked a question, how can you provide any kind of answer? :D